# Why aren't any buildings coming up on my break-out Industrial area despite having demand in Cities: Skylines

Tags: cities-skylines

I'm trying to expand my city's industrial footprint. Acquired the second square besides the first "main square" & I'm trying to build an industrial district around there.

[image]

My City has adequate demand for Industries, yet no buildings seem to come up in the second Industrial hub. Why is this so? What can I do to get those buildings up and running?

Comment: My guess is because access sucks.  There's (effectively) one way in and only one way out.  People can't even get to and from the main part of your city.

Comment: Is there enough resedenial to fill all of the industial

Comment: @GabrielSchmidt yes, there is.  the residential on the breakout section was zoned long after Industrial was setup, and the residential is populated despite lower demand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this is because the breakout region wasn't connected by a power source. I realized this by putting in a better access system, as mentioned [by MBraedley](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211504/why-arent-any-buildings-coming-up-on-my-break-oout-industrial-area-despite-havi#comment286336_211504). Despite the access, the Industrial buildings weren't coming up.

After connecting the power lines, the Industrial buildings started coming up immediately.

To reconfirm this is the problem, I went back to my original save without the improved access and drew power lines - and the Industries came up almost immediately.